# show text when clicking on a 3D object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to Unity and am currently working on a small project.

My problem is this.

I want to display text when I click on the cube.

I have a total of four different cubes, all of which should display different text when clicked.

The solution I have so far works, but of course now when I click on the cubes the same text comes up and if I assign each cube its own text they all appear at once.

The cubes should also rotate and when clicked on just stop and display the text.

I tried it with the Event Trigger System and assign different texts, but without success.

Any suggestion for a solution?

I tried it with the Event Trigger System and assign different texts, but without success.

Any suggestion for a solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhQEN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using input.GetMouseButtonDown, when you click anywhere all
   the boxes run the same code, you don't specify which box is clicked
   you only looking for a click, I suggest you use raycast to send a
   ray to detect which box you are clicking and run ,
2. Add this script to the camera or player and give all the boxes gameobject a "Box" Tag :

   ```
   void Update()
    {
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
   {

     RaycastHit hit;
     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

     if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
     {
         Transform objectHit = hit.transform;

         if (objectHit.CompareTag("Box"))
         {
             objectHit.GetComponent<Rotator>().RotateObject();
         }
     }
     }
    }
   ```
3. add this function to the Rotator Script and remove the code from update :

   ```
    public void RotateObject()
     {
        if (rotateObject)
     { 

         rotateObject = false;
         Text.SetActive(true);

     }
     else
     {
         rotateObject = true;
         Text.SetActive(false);
     }
      }
    }
   ```